# How to set Model property, toggle a boolean in Django query?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible in my Detail view below, to set the boolean within a model to be false ?
I looked through the django documentation (queryset) for something like a `.set()` method for this, it seems to exist but not applicable to this particular case.
How can I toggle the `unread` boolean in my `Models.py`, through my view ?

Also, what am I misunderstanding here and what is the better/appropriate way to do this  ?

Models.py:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name = 'recipient',null = True)
    sender = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser,related_name = 'messages')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, blank = True)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    unread = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

Views.py :

```
### Message detail class
class MessageInboxDetail(DetailView):
'''
This view lets the user view the details of a message created
'''
context_object_name = 'message_detail'
model = Message
template_name = "myInbox/message_detail.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MessageInboxDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({
        'message_detail': Message.unread.set(False) }) # Message(unread=True/False)
    return context
```

Comment: `context['instance'].unread = False` and `context['instance'].save()`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I get a linting warning : "Instance of BooleanField has no set member"

Then I get a KeyError for 'instance' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not set the field of a model instance with a `.set(..)` call, but by assigning to the attribute (behind the curtains, Django has patched the `__get__` and `__set__` functions).

We can thus obtain the `message` object by retrieving it out of the context (with `context['message_detail']`, and then change it state, and finally save the updated version to the database. For example:

```
class MessageInboxDetail(DetailView):
    '''
    This view lets the user view the details of a message created
    '''
    context_object_name = 'message_detail'
    model = Message
    template_name = "myInbox/message_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MessageInboxDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        message = context['message_detail']
        message.unread = False
        message.save()
        return context
```

I however do not know if it is a good idea to mark a message as read in the detail view, it can result in code duplication, which is usually not a good idea.

Comment: "
I however do not know if it is a good idea to mark a message as read in the detail view, it can result in code duplication, which is usually not a good idea.
"
Can you explain further please ?
Is there a better/simpler way to implement this feature in django ?

Comment: @timi95: it might be better to implement a `mark_read` function in the `Message` class itself. Furthermore it could happen that if the view fails (or for example the network connection of the user stops working), the message is marked read without the user actually having read the message. If you want to prevent that, an AJAX call to a view that marks messages as read might perhaps be more robust.